# dijit dialog wont open in custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to open a dijit dialog in a custom widget but the dialog wont open.  What could I be doing wrong?  The plunker code is here: `<http://plnkr.co/edit/bpsQ4GHpzxIQzF4sh65z>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside script.js change the code to this code

```
   require(["custom/MyWidget", "dojo/domReady!"], function(MyWidget) {
      var myWdg = new MyWidget({});
      myWdg.myDialog.startup();
      myWdg.myDialog.show();
    });
```

Or try this plunkr [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hkiHj6RdOfnQoJ3o5SjK?p=preview)

Comment: the dialog is located in template.html and myDialog is an attach point to the template.   I tried this:
var d = new MyWidget({});
  d.startup();//also this.myDialog.startup();
  this.myDialog.show();
but still not seeing the dialog

Thanks for your help

Comment: Aw missed that ;-) But I've edited my anwer to a working one.